# Passing control hotkeys to VirtualBox with AutoHotKey

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I use VirtualBox on Windows 10 host, and my guest OS is linux openSUSE. Since I still need many windows control hotkeys, I do not use Auto Capture Keyboard in VirtualBox. As a drawback, I can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  to cycle through applications when I am inside Linux, and instead I end up with cycling through windows applications. I'd like to fix that with AutoHotKey: when VirtualBox window is active, reassign Win+Tab so that it sends <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  to Linux (instead of popping up windows desktop chooser). But whatever script I figure out, it doesn't work the way I want. E.g., this one has no any effect at all:

```
#IfWinActive, openSUSE13.2 [Running] - Oracle VM VirtualBox
LWin & Tab:: ControlSend, QWidget7, !{Tab}
```

(though if in the second line I write !Tab instead of !{Tab}, it works like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut in Linux applications). I also used Send and SendInput instead of ControlSend, but that doesn't help. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I think your goal is not achievable. no matter to which control you send the keys, be it Virtualbox or firefox or whatever, the key sequence !{Tab} will always be captured by Windows itself.

Comment: But it seems that the guest OS inside the VirtualBox does receive the signal - as I wrote, if I write "Send !Tab", and if I then press Alt+Tab, this does act in the guest OS, but it acts in a wrong way (as if I pressed Alt+T). So the signal is there, the only thing left is to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Sure Alt+T can be passed to the guest OS cause it is not trapped by Windows, but I'm pretty sure ALT+TAB cannot.

Comment: Well, probably I failed to write it more explicitly :) The point is that when I press the key combination Alt+Tab on my physical keyboard, the signal is sent to the guest OS, but it is interpreted incorrectly. Nevertheless, that implies that the Alt+Tab signal does pass to the guest OS.

Comment: I think it's passed incorrectly, instead of interpreted incorrectly.  What actually passed to the Virtualbox Window I think is, Alt+t, then a, then b.